# Server listen socket held by background child processes after parent termination

Tags: sockets

I have a software monitor (that is used to restart dead processes) that runs a webserver for providing status information to a centralized application manager.  There is an issue of reusing the webserver listen socket if the monitor needs to be restarted because of the child process inheriting the socket details.  Can anyone suggest an elegant solution to this problem please?  Ideally one would like to have the monitor restart processes with a "clean" environment!

The listing below illustrates the problem:

```
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# cat listener.py

import socket, os

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    serversocket.bind(('', 9999))
    serversocket.listen(5)
    os.system('sleep 12345 &')
    os.system('sleep 54321 &')
    while True:
        (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
        print address
finally:
    serversocket.close()

[root@aws-dev01 listen]# python listener.py &
[1] 7795
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# kill 7795
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# netstat -anp | grep 9999
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7797/sleep
[1]+  Terminated              python listener.py
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# kill 7797
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# netstat -anp | grep 9999
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7799/sleep
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# kill 7799
[root@aws-dev01 listen]# netstat -anp | grep 9999
[root@aws-dev01 listen]#
```

Thanks
Colin

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? It doesn't make sense. If the web server is still running, why would you want to restart it? And if you do, why aren't you killing the old one first? And why the sleeps? Are you sure you aren't really running into the TIME_WAIT state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is for the serversocket to be automatically closed in the child process(es) as soon as their exec() returns.  Fortunately there is a call to enable exactly that behavior... just add the following lines after your socket() all in your example code:

```
flags = fcntl.fcntl(serversocket, fcntl.F_GETFD)
fcntl.fcntl(serversocket, fcntl.F_SETFD, flags | fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
```

(Note that this is a POSIX-y thing so I'd be very surprised if it worked under Windows)

Ref:  Python issue [12107](http://bugs.python.org/issue12107)